# How to getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(Uri imageUri) to work?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-wallpaper

So, there are two questions that are the same as this(
[How to use getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent method in WallpaperManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998177/how-to-use-getcropandsetwallpaperintent-method-in-wallpapermanager) AND [How to use getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094023/how-to-use-getcropandsetwallpaperintent)
), but there are no answers to both of them. In hope of an answer I'm asking this - how to get this method to work.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(android.net.Uri) that doesn't help my brains.

And this doesn't work

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://lv.revo.inspicfootballhd/drawable/v1");
Intent intent = new Intent(wallpaperManager.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

logcat shows this

```
5891-5891/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: lv.revo.inspicfootballhd, PID: 5891
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image URI must be of the content scheme type
            at android.app.WallpaperManager.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(WallpaperManager.java:760)
            at lv.revo.inspicfootballhd.MainActivity.onTouch(MainActivity.java:236)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7701)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2338)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1568)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2465)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2285)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3947)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3518)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3411)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3392)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5532)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5512)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5483)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5612)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So, according to documentation "The image URI that will be set in the intent. The must be a content URI and its provider must resolve its type to "image/*""

The image is in .jpg format. I'm going to keep finding a solution to this tomorrow. I just hoped that someone smarter knows the answer to my question.

**EDIT/UPDATE 1:**
So I managed to change uri to Content Uri, I believe so. Did that using this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23223556/2727408

Now it shows this

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot use passed URI to set wallpaper; check that the type returned by ContentProvider matches image/*
            at android.app.WallpaperManager.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(WallpaperManager.java:792)
            at lv.revo.inspicfootballhd.MainActivity.onTouch(MainActivity.java:244)
```

I tried to check the type using ContentResolver getType(contentURI), it returned null. Now I'll try to find how to change that to image/*

The code so far looks like this

```
Uri uri = ResourceToUri(getApplicationContext(), imageArray[j]);
File wallpaper_file = new File(uri.getPath());
Uri contentURI = getImageContentUri(getApplicationContext(), wallpaper_file.getAbsolutePath());

ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
Log.d("CONTENT TYPE: ", "IS: " + cr.getType(contentURI));

Intent intent = new Intent(wallpaperManager.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(contentURI));
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks so far.

**EDIT/UPDATE 2:**
Created new question about my new issue here: 
[How to change type to image/*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793404/how-to-change-type-to-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says, you need a content URI. Content URIs allow you to share files with temporary read and write permissions.

Check out: [Get a Content URI from a File URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207604/get-a-content-uri-from-a-file-uri)

Comment: Thank you so far, I got another error and I updated my question.

Comment: You should accept this answer and open a new question, then. It'll help others who at looking for an answer to your 2nd question as well as bring attention to your new issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
File wallpaper_file = new File(uri.getPath());
 Uri contentURI = getImageContentUri(getApplicationContext(),wallpaper_file);

 ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
 Log.d("CONTENT TYPE: ", "IS: " + cr.getType(contentURI));

 Intent intent = new Intent(wallpaperManager.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(contentURI));
startActivity(intent);

public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
    String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID},
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
            new String[]{filePath}, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media");
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "" + id);
    } else {
        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
            return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```